# Which is the correct approach out of the two?

Tags: xslt

I'm having an XML and likes to retrieve and concatenate values

Below is the Sample XML from which we need to retrieve the values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
<docBody>
  <employee>
     <employeeNumber>595</employeeNumber>
  </employee>
  <employeeAddress>
    <empAddress>1</empAddress>
    <empAddress2>1</empAddress2>
  </employeeAddress>
 </docBody>
 <Messages />
 </Document>
```

Method1:

```
<xsl:template match="employee">

<xsl:variable name="empNbr">
<xsl:value-of select="employeeNumber"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="empAddress">
<xsl:value-of select="../employeeDetails/employeeAddress"/>
</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="empAddress2">
 <xsl:value-of select="../employeeDetails/empAddress2"/>
 </xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="concat($empNbr,$empAddress,$empAddress2)"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Method2:

```
<xsl:template match="employee">

<xsl:value-of select="concat(<xsl:value-of select="employeeNumber"/>,
<xsl:value-of select="../employeeDetails/employeeAddress"/>,
<xsl:value-of select="../employeeDetails/empAddress2"/>)"/>

 </xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to write variable declarations like so

```
<xsl:variable name="empNbr" select="employeeNumber" />
```

This means `empNbr` now references the `employeeNumber` directly. By using `xsl:value-of` this effectively gets the text value of `empNbr` and assigns it to the variable.

Your second method is not valid XSLT. The expression you are looking for is this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(employeeNumber, ../employeeDetails/employeeAddress, ../employeeDetails/empAddress2)" />
```

Or you could have three separate `xsl:value-of` statements.

```
<xsl:value-of select="employeeNumber"/>
<xsl:value-of select="../employeeDetails/employeeAddress"/>
<xsl:value-of select="../employeeDetails/empAddress2"/>
```